# How do I limit the object graph in JAX-RS on a per method basis?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have an entity class that contains usernames and email addresses. For some part of my application I require a list of users with the id, username and email address. For other parts I require a list WITHOUT specific fields (namely email address in this case) being sent across the wire. Is there an annotation I can put on a method that limits the object graph created that I can put on the getListWithoutEmails method?

i.e. @LimitTo(value = { "id", "username" }) or @Ignore(value = { "emailAddress" })

Environment is Wildfly and its pre-bundled JAX-RS.

Here is the entity class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User {
  @XmlElement
  private Long id;
  @XmlElement
  private String username;
  @XmlElement
  private String emailAddress;
}
```

Here is the JAX-RS class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("userList")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserList {
  @GET
  @Path("/getListWithEmails/{start:\\d+}/{limit:\\d+}/{sortColumn}/{sortDirection}")
  @HasRoleEmailReader
  public List<User> getListWithEmails(@PathParam("start")
  final int start, @PathParam("limit")
  final int limit, @PathParam("sortColumn")
  final String sortColumn, @PathParam("sortDirection")
  final String sortDirection) {
    getUsers(...);
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/getListWithoutEmails/{start:\\d+}/{limit:\\d+}/{sortColumn}/{sortDirection}")
  public List<User> getListWithoutEmails(@PathParam("start")
  final int start, @PathParam("limit")
  final int limit, @PathParam("sortColumn")
  final String sortColumn, @PathParam("sortDirection")
  final String sortDirection) {
    getUsers(...);
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS is not responsible for serializing custom return types, so you should also look into whatever framework is used for the actual serialisation process. Since I don't know what library is used, I give you some general steps that should do what you want to achieve:

1. Create a custom annotation for you method.
2. Create a [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e5269) - you can add `@Produce` to restrict it to JSON return types.
3. Implement [`isWritable`](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#isWriteable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation%5b%5d,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29), check the `annotations` argument for your annotation here.
4. Implement [`writeTo`](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html#writeTo%28T,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation%5B%5D,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap,%20java.io.OutputStream%29). If the annotation is present, *customize the serialization process*. How to do this depends on the serialization library you use. Maybe it has a feature to ignore properties, maybe you need to do it by hand.
5. Add `@Provider` to your resource class to use the writer.